# First empty cell

Tags: vba, excel

I've found different solution on the site but they don't solve my problem. The section below is the result of a find where the "FoundCell" address is returned to the worksheet.
What I'm attempting to do is return the "FoundCell" address to cell (1,1) and the rest directly below. I want what my debug line is doing to print on the spreadsheet.

```
Value Found In Cell: $F$2
Value Found In Cell: $F$5
Value Found In Cell: $F$8
Value Found In Cell: $F$9
```

The sheet "program index" contains columns A to F. I'm using the Find to search a comma delimited string in column F. Currently the code is returning the cell address in column F where the string is found. What I need to the entries in column A & B associated with the found address in column F.

```
Sub Find()

Dim SearchRange As Range
Dim FoundCells As Range
Dim FoundCell As Range
Dim Destination As Range
Dim c, d As Range
Dim Row As String


Dim FindWhat As Variant
Dim FindWhat2 As Variant


Set Destination = Sheets("Calculations").Cells(1, 1)
Set SearchRange = Sheets("Program Index").Range("F2:F1000")

Debug.Print Sheets("main").Range("F2")

Sheets("Calculations").Range("A2:A50").Clear

FindWhat = Sheets("Main").Range("F2")
FindWhat2 = "All"

Set FoundCells = FindAll(SearchRange:=SearchRange, _
                        FindWhat:=FindWhat, _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                        MatchCase:=False, _
                        BeginsWith:=vbNullString, _
                        EndsWith:=vbNullString, _
                        BeginEndCompare:=vbTextCompare)

If FoundCells Is Nothing Then
    Debug.Print "Value Not Found"
Else
    Set c = Sheets("Calculations").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    For Each FoundCell In FoundCells
         c.Value = FoundCell.Address   
         Set c = c.Offset(1, 0)
    Next FoundCell
End If

    Set FoundCells = FindAll(SearchRange:=SearchRange, _
                            FindWhat:=FindWhat2, _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                            MatchCase:=False, _
                            BeginsWith:=vbNullString, _
                            EndsWith:=vbNullString, _
                            BeginEndCompare:=vbTextCompare)

If FoundCells Is Nothing Then
    Debug.Print "Value Not Found"
Else
    Set c = Sheets("Calculations").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    For Each FoundCell In FoundCells
         c.Value = FoundCell.Address
         Set c = c.Offset(1, 0)
    Next FoundCell
End If

End Sub
```

I believe the change i need should happen in the "FindAll" however I'm not sure where to modify.

```
If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
    Set FirstFound = FoundCell

    Do Until False ' Loop forever. We'll "Exit Do" when necessary.
        Include = False
        If BeginsWith = vbNullString And EndsWith = vbNullString Then
            Include = True
        Else
            If BeginsWith <> vbNullString Then
                If StrComp(Left(FoundCell.Text, Len(BeginsWith)), BeginsWith, BeginEndCompare) = 0 Then
                    Include = True
                End If
            End If
            If EndsWith <> vbNullString Then
                If StrComp(Right(FoundCell.Text, Len(EndsWith)), EndsWith, BeginEndCompare) = 0 Then
                    Include = True
                End If
            End If
        End If
        If Include = True Then
            If ResultRange Is Nothing Then
                Set ResultRange = FoundCell
            Else
                Set ResultRange = Application.Union(ResultRange, FoundCell)
            End If
        End If
        Set FoundCell = SearchRange.FindNext(after:=FoundCell)
        If (FoundCell Is Nothing) Then
            Exit Do
        End If
        If (FoundCell.Address = FirstFound.Address) Then 'modify to find program number and description
            Exit Do
        End If

    Loop
End If

Set FindAll = ResultRange
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 FoundCell.Copy Sheets("Calculations").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1,0)
```

**EDIT:** maybe this is what you're looking for:

```
Dim c as range

If FoundCells Is Nothing Then
    Debug.Print "Value Not Found"
Else
    Set c = Sheets("Calculations").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1,0)
    For Each FoundCell In FoundCells
         Debug.Print "Value Found In Cell: " & FoundCell.Address
         c.value = FoundCell.Address()
         'add values from the same row as FoundCell
         c.offset(0, 1).value = FoundCell.EntireRow.Cells(1).value 'from colA
         c.offset(0, 2).value = FoundCell.EntireRow.Cells(2).value 'from colB
         Set c = c.offset(1,0)
    Next FoundCell
End If
```

Comment: Be sides being nicer what does this fix exactly?

Comment: Good question I suppose - I skipped through the question and based on the title assumed the OP was having problem locating the last cell and didn't really decipher the tortuous line in question.  Re-reading the question it's not really clear what the OP wants.

Comment: Thanks! That's why I was asking I have no idea what the question is either, thought you caught something I missed.

Comment: I know poorly asked question. What I needed this for was the cell address from the "foundcell". This returns the value in column F and i need the values in column A and B from the associated row from "FoundCell" Can I change the "c.value" offset to retrieve the needed column data?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can make whatever changes you need, but it's difficult to tell from the question exactly what your final aim is.

Comment: I added additional code sample and refined my question. Thank you for your help on this. I'm only a few months into VBA so everything helps.

Answer (score 0):

To get your debug.print lines to show in Column A, rows 1 to n, you could do something like:

```
Dim FoundCells As Range, FoundCell As Range
Dim rDest As Range
Set rDest = Worksheets("Calculations").Range("A1")

'For testing
Set FoundCells = Union(Range("f2"), Range("f5"), Range("f8"), Range("f9"))

If FoundCells Is Nothing Then
        rDest.Value = "Value Not Found"
    Else
        For Each FoundCell In FoundCells
             rDest.Value = "Value Found In Cell: " & FoundCell.Address
             Set rDest = rDest(2, 1)
        Next FoundCell
    End If
```